# C++ two dimmensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

So i need to make this by using two dimmensional array, i'm stuck on first column...
In the first column there are numbers from 2.0 to 3.0 adding up by 0.1.

[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0wS6.jpg)

```
#include using namespace std;

int main()
{ int x[0][0] = {{2.00};

cout <<" x 1/x x^2 x^3 x^4"<<endl; 
cout <<"---- ---- ---- --------"<<endl;
 
for (int i = 0.1; i < 3.0; ++i) {
 
return 0; }
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste the text *as text* into the question. Also please learn how to create a [mcve] and how to [edit] your questions. And of course please take some time to read [ask] as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "I'm stuck" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: `int x[0][0] = {{2.00};` does nothing close to what you think it does, and has a typo on top of that. For loop bracing is all wrong. Your table heading is mis-aligned, and you have it staring right at you in the code. And most importantly, you haven't even tried anything. Please read [ask] and [mre].

Comment: @ytlo Your edit added context and details not in the original question. It's pure speculation.

Answer (score 2):

ok our target is to get those columns `x, 1/x, x^2, x^3, x^4`

we can get the first column `x` by `x[row][0] = 2.0 + (0.1 * row);`

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 11; ++row)
    x[row][0] = 2.0 + (0.1 * row); // update first column
```

that's will iterate all rows in column 0 (first column)
and means that each row in the first column equal 2.0 + (0.1 multiply by the index of the row)

so the second column `1/x` just gets 1 over the first column
`x[row][1] = 1 / x[row][0];`

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 11; ++row){
    x[row][0] = 2.0 + (0.1 * row); // update first column
    x[row][1] = 1 / x[row][0]; // update second column
}
```

so after gets the values of all rows in the first column (index 0)
the values of the rows in the second column will be 1 / the values of the rows in the **first column**
`x[row][1] = 1 / x[row][0];`

now the last three columns `x^2, x^3, x^4` is just the first column power (2, 3, 4)

```cpp
x[row][2] = pow(x[row][0], 2); // values of the 3rd column is first column power 2
x[row][3] = pow(x[row][0], 3); // values of the 4th column is first column power 3
x[row][4] = pow(x[row][0], 3); // values of the 5th column is first column power 4
```

we just take the values from the first column and power it with the index of the column *(2, 3, 4 are the indexes of 3rd, 4th, 5th columns)*

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 11; ++row){
    x[row][0] = 2.0 + (0.1 * row); // update 1st column
    x[row][1] = 1 / x[row][0]; // update 2nd column
    x[row][2] = pow(x[row][0], 2); // update 3rd column
    x[row][3] = pow(x[row][0], 3); // update 4st column
    x[row][4] = pow(x[row][0], 3); // update 5st column

}
```

the last three line we can shortcut them with a for loop

```cpp
for(int row = 0; row < 11; ++row){
    x[row][0] = 2.0 + (0.1 * row);
    x[row][1] = 1 / x[row][0];
    for(int column = 2; column < 5; ++column)
        x[row][column] = pow(x[row][0], column);
}
```

so we finish, we build the matrix just like the picture
I write the complete code That giving the output like the picture

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> // pow
#include <iomanip> //setprecision, setw()

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x[11][5];

    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        x[i][0] = 2.0 + 0.1 * i;
        x[i][1] = 1 / x[i][0];
        for (int j = 2; j < 5; ++j)
            x[i][j] = pow(x[i][0], j);
    }
    // print the matrix
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed; // Round numbers to two decimal places
    cout <<" x     1/x    x^2    x^3    x^4" << '\n';
    cout <<"----  ----   ----   -----  -----\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            cout << x[i][j] << setw(7);
        cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output should be:

```
 x     1/x    x^2    x^3    x^4
----  ----   ----   -----  -----
2.00   0.50   4.00   8.00  16.00      
2.10   0.48   4.41   9.26  19.45      
2.20   0.45   4.84  10.65  23.43      
2.30   0.43   5.29  12.17  27.98      
2.40   0.42   5.76  13.82  33.18      
2.50   0.40   6.25  15.62  39.06      
2.60   0.38   6.76  17.58  45.70      
2.70   0.37   7.29  19.68  53.14      
2.80   0.36   7.84  21.95  61.47      
2.90   0.34   8.41  24.39  70.73      
3.00   0.33   9.00  27.00  81.00
```

Comment: Could you please explain first 'for'. Thank you!

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged as they tend to promote [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming), which is bad. Please take some time to [read about how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @DanaEgle I edit the answer and gave some explanation

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What do you think now? It's my first time answering anyway

Comment: Thank you! You helped me alot! :)